# Image upload in a textarea

Tags: image, tinymce

I need a rich textarea in which we have the option to insert images from the local file-system and upload it to the server (also S3 - but it can done with a background task).

I am currently using tinymce but it does not have the feature to insert image from the local filesystem.

What can I use to get such a functionality?

NB - I am using PHP as the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) seems quite good. I used it some time ago and it developed since... You would have to buy CKFinder probably (for $59 per Website...)

... and then there are the TinyMCE Plugins for this that cost almost the same:
http://www.tinymce.com/

If you are looking for a free plugin to TinyMCE or CKEditor with local file browsing google for TinyMCE and iBrowser, TinyFCK, [Kae’s File Manager](http://kfm.verens.com/), Ajax File Manager,   [TinyBrowser](http://www.lunarvis.com/products/tinymcefilebrowserwithupload.php). (I got the list from [http://www.tyssendesign.com.au](http://articles/cms/file-and-image-management-plugins-for-tinymce/)). I would go with the Tiny Browser or the Ke's Filemanager and keep TinyMCE because its already there (But Do have a look at CKEditor - its quite good and those two filemanagers can plug into it too)

Answer (score 1):

You are not the first to stumble over this problem. Have [a look here](http://pascal.vanhecke.info/2005/08/25/image-upload-plugin-for-tinymce/) for a brief overview over solutions.